# Material Design Top App Bar Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, material-design, babeljs

I'm new to working with javascript imports and things like webpack and babel. So, I apologize if my terminology is wrong.

I am trying to get Google's Material Design to work with a test project, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The css work easy enough, but the Instantiation, just wont take.

I have a button in just to make sure it is working and I can get that to work, just no the Top App Bar.

```
import {MDCTopAppBar} from '@material/top-app-bar';

import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple';

const buttonRipple = new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));

// Instantiation
const topAppBarElement = document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar');
const topAppBar = new MDCTopAppBar(topAppBarElement);

<header class="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--fixed">
        <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
            <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
            <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</a>
            <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Project</span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </header>
```

My code is copied directly from the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/top-app-bar/), but the menu icon has a line underneath and the animation doesn't show up.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?
If so how?

I know I can't import stuff from local files on codepen, but [this is what my Top App Bar looks like](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqaEJm)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes to find this and wonders what to do about this. The code that google has on their documentation is using  instead of a .

On their demo page they have the correct code.

Change this:

```
<a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</a>
```

Into this:

```
<button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</button>
```